# POST Rest Call in Swift

Tags: swift, rest, post

I am trying to work with REST calls in Swift (complete beginner), and I was looking at trying to do a POST call with a JSON payload, and then trying to display the response in the console. Is there a very simple example of how to achieve this, I have been super confused with my first experience in mobile and haven't found a tutorial that has helped me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this excellent presentation:

https://realm.io/news/chris-eidhof-micro-libraries-swift/

with this associated gist:

https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/26bda788f13b3e8a279c

And then, when you've worked through that, head over to Alamofire, and use their higher level API.

Note that you can use playgrounds for the first example, but if you run into stability concerns, you can create a OSX application, and rip out the NSApplication stuff to just end up with a command line in a bundle.  This is what I use when testing networking stuff, and I think this is what the presenter is doing as well (he was not using a playground).

PS. There were some subtle changes to the gist after the presentation - function arguments changed, if I recall correctly, but you can easily comment them out and still use the gist as the basis of the presentation.